# build source Apache open office

Tags: apache, build

I try build source apache open office, follow link : 
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Building_Guide_AOO/Step_by_step#Windows_7.
But run command ./bootstrap on cygwin then output error message :./bootstrap: No such file or directory

Please help me!

Comment: what does `echo $SourceMain` return?  And why the Android tag?

Comment: 1. SourceMain = /cygdrive/d/source/aoo-trunk/main. 2. I want study source code(export msoffice to PDFs). after, porting source to android.

Comment: 3. If build source apache open office, What is product?